# Replace on Date colum

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to run a replace and update on a date column in Postgresql.

```
UPDATE table SET date_time = REPLACE(date_time, '12:', '00:');
```

I've tried casting as text. But still errors.

The error I get is

> function replace(timestamp without time zone, unknown, unknown) does not exist

I'm guessing it's not picking it up due to the column's data type. But I'm not quite sure how to achieve what I'm after now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast `date_time` to `text`, do the replacement and then cast the result to `timestamp` again. BTW, what are you trying to achieve? Isn't it a presentation format issue?

```sql
UPDATE "table" 
  SET date_time = replace(date_time::text, ' 12:', ' 00:')::timestamp;
```

Comment: No, it's not a presentation issue. One of the developers forgot to set the time to 24 hours. P.s Worked perfectly thanks.